# Storing 'pairing' information with Google TV 'Anymote Protocol'

Tags: android, google-tv

I've implemented an application based off of the BlackJackRemote in the google-tv-samples (https://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/) and am having to pair the application to the GTV with every session. I've looked through the open source Google TV Remote application but it looks like it requires pairing each session as well. Is there something built into the AnymoteLibrary to retain paired sessions, or some pointers on implementing something like that myself?

My intuition is that I'll need to modify the AnymoteLibrary directly to get this functionality, but maybe it's already available and I've overlooked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creator of Able Remote made a very nice library to handle this sort of thing:

https://github.com/entertailion/Anymote-for-Java (pure Java implementation of Anymote)
https://github.com/entertailion/Android-Anymote (Android project that uses said implementation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. Infact The Google TV remote app does not make you pair everytime you open the app. Its only when the connection is lost that you need to pair again. The same can be replicated in the AnymoteLibrary. I am planning to release an update to the library for it soon.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear. I meant to ask if AnymoteLibrary supported remembering pairing sessions after connections are lost (like if I reboot the phone/tablet/tv). It seems that isn't the case, but it sounds like you mean to add that support in the library sometime in the future.

Comment: It could remember the device IP, but you would have to click on the IP address and re-establish the pairing session. Basically once the connection is lost, it needs to re-authenticate itself ( thats pairing) to establish new connection.